# Add private note after checkout in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

I've setup a custom function by using the `woocommerce_thankyou hook.`I want to add a private note during this function.

How Can I implement this?

Comment: You can't do that in a simple way in `woocommerce_thankyou` hook as you don't submit anything in that page.

Comment: Actually I've found the following function: $order->add_order_note();

I think this should work if I would simply place a string in the first attribute right?

`$order->add_order_note( 'some text to add to a private note', false);`

I'm having more problems with my code, so I can't test it yet

Comment: If is not a field that you want to display on Order Receive , of course you can use `add_order_note()` method … But I think that this is not what you are looking at.